# Check real FPS from NDI source

Tags: video, frame-rate, live-streaming, obs, ndi

I have NDI source self-written with NDI SDK. I send frames with predefined FPS (25, 30, 50, 60). I can view this stream with NDI Studio Monitor or OBS Studio. But I can't check real FPS. Could someone tell me how I can check the FPS on the some receiver?

Comment: Are you trying to determine the FPS of what you're generating?  Or, the FPS as sent to NDI?  Or, the FPS received over NDI?

Comment: Yes, I can determine FPS, sent to NDI. But for check I want to calculate real FPS on the receiver side. And my question what receiver I can use to check some characteristics of the NDI stream (such FPS and maybe some other parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into this too without any success to date. My thought was to use a fps counter for a game, but they don't seem to be able to access that data from NDI Studio Monitor.

My guess as to the reason is that the NDI decoding is a CPU based task and those frame counters are expecting GPU's, on-board or external, to do the task of rendering frames.